# Mix two audio files mp3 in Android

Tags: applications

After a period of research, I found that Android seems in no way to mix two mp3 audio files together. I have suggested using SoX & Lame. Sox by default does not include mp3 support because of licensing issues with mp3 format. I have successfully run the installtion command line mix two audio files mp3 on Ubuntu after install SoX & LAME in terminal.

```
sox -m inputa.mp3 inputb.mp3 mixed.mp3
```

The last issue is now integrated to run in Android Sox with Lame. Do you have any way to make the mix two files audio mp3 in Android? We are discussing here, but everything is still unresolved.

https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg/pull/2

Can you help me! Thank you very much.